# Why does Visual Studio 2010 / Expression Web 4 have XHTML as default?

Tags: html, visual-studio-2010

I was wondering this.  Why not HTML 4.x or even 5?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

What really should I be using instead, if any?

Comment: HTML5 wasn't yet cool when the Visual Studio 2010 DP was released.

Comment: Still waiting on a answer to my original question - if you want 50 points!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe we all agree why HTML5 wasn't chosen as the default standard for web pages in Visual Studio 2010. With the release of the 2010 version, HTML5 wasn't even supported, and only some features were implemented in SP1.

So the question is why chose XHTML over HTML 4.01 (and then why chose different versions of XHTML over others).

First of all, this is an excerpt from a MSDN article regarding XHTML support ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc57y7e(v=vs.100).aspx ):

> Creating Web pages that are conformant with XHTML standards has several advantages:
>
> - It guarantees that the elements in the pages are well formed.
> - Because many browsers are increasingly moving toward supporting XHTML, creating pages that conform to XHTML standards helps ensure that your pages render consistently in all browsers.
> - Using XHTML helps to make pages conform more readily to accessibility standards.
> - XHTML is extensible, allowing the definition of new elements.
> - An XHTML page is much easier to read programmatically for situations in which the Web page is processed by a computer instead of being read by users, and the document can be manipulated using transformations.

Now, how do you choose between different versions of XHTML (1.0 Transitional, 1.0 Strict and 1.1)?

The main difference between XHTML 1.0 Transitional and Strict is the shift towards more semantic markup (inclusion only of structural elements, and not styling elements, like <font> or <pre>). Transitional still supports these elements and attributes (like <img> width and height) because it is designed for backwards-compatibility (hence the name Transitional) while Strict doesn't, and encourages the use of CSS instead of markup.

So, the idea here is that you use Strict when you have understood that you need to separate style (CSS) from markup (HTML).

But why not chose XHTML 1.1 (also supported by VS 2010) instead of XHTML 1.0 Strict? Aside from some minor tweaks (removal of the "name" attribute for <a> and <map>, the removal of the "lang" attribute in favor of "xml:lang" and the addition of the ruby element) there are no major differences when it comes to specific markup. The major downside of XHTML 1.1 is that it requires you to transmit your content as "application/xhtml+xml" instead of "text/html", and the browser support for this was limited with earlier versions.

So, why did Microsoft decide to use XHTML 1.0 Transitional as their default DOCTYPE?

- instead of HTML because all of the advantages mentioned above from the MSDN article
- instead of XHTML 1.0 Strict and 1.1 because you always want backwards compatibility in your IDE, and if they used Strict for example, if you had opened your XHTML 1.0 Transitional with <font> and <pre> in it you would have gotten a lot of errors, which could be avoided.
- internally, and this is only a guess, XHTML is slightly faster to parse (because XML parsing is generally a little bit faster than HTML). Although for an user the difference is not notable, for a large program like Visual Studio every little tweak counts.

I mentioned only Visual Studio, but same applies to Expression.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if BoltClock is 100%. HTML5 was surely cool from the very beginning. It is the next standard and can't be ignored.. But it really didn't become a recommended standard until after VS 2010 was released, I'm sure. As a matter of fact, they're still working on it and if the following article is correct, it is not estimated to be complete until 2014:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5

Nonetheless, I would say to download whatever extension to VS to get full HTML5 CSS3 intellisense and work with it so that you can become aquainted with it's nifty features and enjoy using them on your web apps if you're so inclined.

p.s. I strongly encourage you to take advantage of VS 2012 or the express version of it. Yes, the interface is horrible in my opinion (compared to 2010's awesome interface). But the features that have been added (such as MVC4) such as bundling and minification is waaay cool!

Check it out!:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386063.aspx

See: ASP.NET 4.5 Core Services for what I'm excited about.

@Martin Smith. Agreed, you certainly can get these features without having to download a new version of VS. I have just found that downloading the latest version (for those that are inclined) will give us an already put together package of many of the latest features of the .NET 4.5 :)

I appreciate you bringing that out, though. Because my answer was incomplete without it for sure. Now everyone wants to have to just abandon an older version of VS (especially by just 2 years) when they can just add these packages to their existing, working version.

This is exactly why I like StackOverflow. The array of contributors available helps us to have a well rounded understanding of options available.. :)

Comment: Bundling and minification is available through NuGet for 2010 via Microsoft ASP.NET Web Optimization Framework 1.0.0

Comment: Thanks for the info, though still waiting for an answer to the original question.

Comment: @TeaDrinkingGeek I do believe the answer to your question is contained here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_xhtml.asp It speaks about XHTML as being "a stricter and cleaner version of HTML 4.01" among other things. Check it out!

Comment: HTML5 was not 'surely cool from the very beginning' - a lot of us were hoping that XHTML's strictness would win out over HTML's tag soup.

Comment: @Karpie I really was referring to the introduction to the new abilities that would come with HTML5 versus the previous version of HTML (I, too, prefer the strictness of XHTML)

Answer (score 0):

I think the choice of the default DOCTYPE could be a matter of browser support.
Given that XHTML 1.0 actually is the XML version of HTML 4.01 and has a long story began when
XML first became 'fashion' (for good reasons already stated in the other answers).

Quoting from W3C site (old page but still useful):
http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/2004/xhtml-faq#need

"XHTML 1.0 comes in three versions: strict, transitional, and frameset. All three of these were deliberately kept as close as possible to HTML 4.01 as XML would allow."

I found simple, short and interesting the following post with suggestion about what doctype to use:

http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/33-the-truth-about-cross-browser-development-and-3-secrets-to-better-compatibility

Hope it helps

Matteo